# check if file exists with wildcards in filename

Tags: c++, file

What i Need for c++:

```
if( fileExists("c:\foo\bar*.txt") ){
  cout << "file exists";
}else{
  cout << "file does not exists";
}
```

Its nearly the same as descripted here: [How to check a file if exists with wildcard in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8752034/how-to-check-a-file-if-exists-with-wildcard-in-java) , but for c++

Comment: Currently [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1257721/can-i-use-a-mask-to-iterate-files-in-a-directory-with-boost) is the closest you'll get to a cross platform solution in C++. Otherwise, there may be platform specific APIs available.

Comment: Since a file system is a concurrent data structure, you should beware that "existence" of a file is not really a meaningful, or even sensible, property. The question "Does file X exist?" has no meaningful answer that you could distinguish from any different answer. I could always answer "yes", and claim that someone just deleted the file as you were about to open it, and you couldn't prove I was wrong. The only meaningful operation on a file system is to *open* a file, which may either succeed or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you haven't specified a platform there are a few options. For POSIX compliant systems there is [the answer from this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8401777/simple-glob-in-c-on-unix-system) (credit his not mine):

> You can use the [`glob()`][1] POSIX library function.

alternatively for windows there is [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1269480/globbing-in-c-c-on-windows):

> Link with `setargv.obj` (or `wsetargv.obj`) and argv[] will be globbed for you similar to how the Unix shells do it:
>
> - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bch7bkk.aspx
>
> I can't vouch for how well it does it though.

Or for a simple cross platform library you could try [shwild](http://www.shwild.org/) or [wildcmp](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1088/Wildcard-string-compare-globbing) or write your own with the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5211752/implementing-a-platform-independent-glob).